# Convert the words of JSONArray into lowercase

Tags: java, gwt

I have a JSONArray which consist of some subjects in it.I want to convert them into lowercase. Single words like Math,Computer are easily converted to lowercase. But my problem is with Computer-Programming it consist of hyphen in between  how to convert this into lowercase. i want this to be done in java. I am using GWT with java i tried these methods:

```
String hsctosmall=hsc.toString().replaceAll("-", "")toLowerCase();

String hsctosmall=hsc.toString().replaceFirst("-", "")toLowerCase();
```

They were of no use.

**INPUT:**
Computer-Programming

**OUTPUT**
computerprogramming

Initially i was doing this:

```
public JSONArray ConvertTS(JSONArray technicaldata)
    {
        for(Object hsc:technicaldata)
        {
            String hsctosmall=hsc.toString().toLowerCase();
            technicaldata.discard(hsc);
            technicaldata.add(hsctosmall);
        }
        return technicaldata;
    }
```

Comment: What is not working with your attempts? Apart from the missing `.` they seem fine.

Comment: it was just to show you the method. its not converting the Computer-Programming to lowercase.

Comment: `its not converting the Computer-Programming to lowercase.` I just showed it to you :)

Answer (score 0):

There will no lowercase for `-`. Only alphabets have case.

Just try

```
System.out.println("Computer-Programming".toLowerCase());
```

[gives you](http://ideone.com/L9izPQ)

```
computer-programming
```

Comment: its not giving this result. While traversing the jsonarray all the other elements are converted into lowercase except Computer-Programming.

Comment: @priya Can you show us the full code ? And also have you tried removing of replaceFirst and replace all methods ?

Comment: @priya `hsc.toString()` can you print that tell me what you are getting ?

Comment: Its a jsonarray that i am traversing i am converting the Object value to String.

Comment: @priya You are converting that only to lower case right ?? Put a Sysout there and note those Strings. So that we can see why the string  is not getting converted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59183/discussion-between-ss--and-priya).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Keppil, your statement is good, except for the missing dot between `replaceAll("-","")` and `toLowerCase()`.

I created a small program with this line and it works:

`String hsctosmall = hsc.toString().replaceAll("-", "").toLowerCase();`

Comment: Ahhh..that must be a typo. In that case the code won't even compile friend.

Comment: I got the problem its changed actually the array values that i am traversing the jsonarray has got the problem.. going to see it tommorow. Thanks all..